How can I integrate pac4j with clojure ring
I'm working to build a clojure ring app and use Shiro for authn/authz.
I saw pac4j can bring in OpenID Connect authentication for a lot of services.
I saw there is no pac4j implementation for clojure ring spec.
I suspect I would have to build one myself?
This should make http request/web context accessible to pac4j in order to handle authentication.
Once that is done I should be able to use buji-pac4j to integrate with Shiro to handle authn/authz ?!

https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/SPEC.md
https://www.pac4j.org/docs/how-to-implement-pac4j-for-a-new-framework.html


Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

With buji-pac4j, you have a bridge between pac4j and Shiro: it means that a pac4j authentication is propragated to the Shiro security context.
This is really for legacy/integration purposes.
In your case, you should just develop a Clojure implementation for pac4j following this guide: https://www.pac4j.org/docs/how-to-implement-pac4j-for-a-new-framework.html
